AWS Glue Shuffle No space left on device error
I have an AWS Glue job running on PySpark that when writing to S3 throws the following error
Lost task 780.1 in stage 677.0 (TID 150416) (172.36.134.20 executor 16): java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(FileDispatcherImpl.java:60)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)`

The job is running this code when failing
df_finance.write.format("parquet").mode('overwrite').save(source_path + "temp/df_finance/")

I have --write-shuffle-files-to-s3 set in the Job Parameters and shuffle is still not using S3. Not sure what I could be missing here and this failure is torturing me at this point. Has anyone gone through this before?
I've tried repartitioning the data, filtering to smaller source datasets and coalescing the writes but none of them seem to work. I've also scaled this to a G4.X machine with 149 workers which is pretty big and that seems to not work as well.
Any help here would be much appreciated
